# How to properly place SimpleDialog class in Flutter/Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I have a code:

```dart
// New Game route
class NewGameRoute extends StatelessWidget {
  const NewGameRoute({key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'New Game',
      home: ListFromCSV(),
    );
  }
}

class ListFromCSV extends StatefulWidget {
  const ListFromCSV({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ListFromCSVState createState() => _ListFromCSVState();
}

class _ListFromCSVState extends State<ListFromCSV> {
  List<List<dynamic>> _listData = [
    [""]
  ];
  int _listCount = 0;
  bool _isFirstLoad = true;
  String assetPath = "files/main.jpg";

  @override
  void initState() {
    _loadCSV();
  }

  // This function is only triggered at init, so we only load csv once
  void _loadCSV() async {
    String rawData = await rootBundle.loadString("files/Text.csv");
    _listData = const CsvToListConverter().convert(rawData);
    assetPath = _listData[_listCount][1] == ""
        ? "files/main.jpg"
        : _listData[_listCount][1];
  }

  // This function is triggered when my button is pressed
  void _nextCSV() {
    setState(() {
      _listData = _listData;
      _listCount < _listData.length - 1
          ? _isFirstLoad
          ? _isFirstLoad = false
          : _listCount++
          : _listCount;
      assetPath =
      _listData[_listCount][1] == "" ? assetPath : _listData[_listCount][1];
    });
  }

  // This function makes buttons visible/invisible
  bool isVisible = true; //will be visible for the first frame

  void _isVisible() {
    setState(() {
      isVisible = !isVisible;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('New Game'),
      ),
      body: Container(
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            image: DecorationImage(
                image: AssetImage(assetPath),
                fit: BoxFit.cover)),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: <Widget>[
            Visibility(
              child: Column(
              children: [
                ClipRRect(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4),
                  child: Stack(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Positioned.fill(
                        child: Container(
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              image: DecorationImage(
                                  image: AssetImage('files/sheet.jpg'),
                                  fit: BoxFit.cover)),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Text(_listData[_listCount][0]),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                  children: [
                    ImageButton(label: 'OK', onButtonTap: _nextCSV),
                    ImageButton(label: 'Hide', onButtonTap: _isVisible),
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            ),
              visible: isVisible,
            ),
            // your other widgets
            Visibility(
              child: ImageButton(label: 'Show', onButtonTap: _isVisible),
              visible: !isVisible,
            )

          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


//Class for a cool button
class ImageButton extends StatelessWidget {
  const ImageButton({Key? key, required this.label, required this.onButtonTap})
      : super(key: key);
  final String label;
  final Function onButtonTap;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return InkWell(
      onTap: () => onButtonTap(),
      child: Container(
        // customize you button shape and size and design
        margin: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8, horizontal: 32),
        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(2)),
            image: DecorationImage(
                image: AssetImage("files/sheet.jpg"), // you can also pass the image dynamically with variable created for the widget.
                fit: BoxFit.cover)),
        child: Center(
          child: Text(
            label,
            style: const TextStyle(
                color: Colors
                    .black, // you can get dominant colour on image and change the text color accordingly or apply shadows to the text
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                fontSize: 16),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And a test file:

**[File](https://mega.nz/file/dpoB1QCQ#2FKXEGNdKgAR7iQUxFLcfWuz_U8ERmWg0xHEVh14bsg)**

I want that if _listData[_listCount](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/SimpleDialog-class.html) is not empty, then my user will see a popup dialog where there will be a question (its text is in _listData[_listCount](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/SimpleDialog-class.html)) and two answers (their texts are in _listData[_listCount ][3] and _listData[_listCount][4] respectively).

Since I am a newbie, I took the code from the [official documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/SimpleDialog-class.html) as a basis:

I tried to modify it to fit my code. As a result I have this:

```dart
Future<void> _askedToLead() async {
  switch (await showDialog<Question>(
    context: context
    builder: (BuildContext context) {
      return SimpleDialog(
        title: const Text(_listData[_listCount][2]),
        children: <Widget>[
          SimpleDialogOption(
            onPressed: () { Navigator.pop(context, Question.Answer1); },
            child: const Text(_listData[_listCount][3]),
          ),
          SimpleDialogOption(
            onPressed: () { Navigator.pop(context, Question.Answer2); },
            child: const Text(_listData[_listCount][4]),
          ),
        ],
      );
    }
  )) {
    case Question.Answer1:
      // Let's go.
      // ...
    break;
    case Question.Answer2:
      // ...
    break;
    case null:
      //dialog dismissed
    break;
  }
}
```

1. Is it correct? And if so, where should I put it in my code? Should it be a separate class?
2. How should I modify this piece of code to call the SimpleDialog class?

```dart
// This function is triggered when my button is pressed
  void _nextCSV() {
    setState(() {
      _listData = _listData;
      _listCount < _listData.length - 1
          ? _isFirstLoad
          ? _isFirstLoad = false
          :_listCount++
          :_listCount;
      assetPath=
      _listData[_listCount][1] == "" ? assetPath : _listData[_listCount][1];
    });
  }
```

Thanks in advance.